# TypeError: Cannot read property 'delete' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am getting an error (`Cannot read property 'delete' of undefined`). It's probably an easy fix but I can't seem to figure out how to fix it.

The error:

```
message.delete({timeout: 1000})

TypeError: Cannot read property 'delete' of undefined
```

My code:

```js
const client = new Client();

let count = 0;
let timeout;

client.on('message', ({ channel, content, member, message }) => {
  if (channel.id === '933939208102494270') {
    if (member.user.bot) return;

    if (Number(content) === count + 1) {
      count++;

      if (timeout) clearTimeout(timeout);

      timeout = setTimeout(
        () => channel.send(++count).catch(console.error),

        100
      );
    } else if (member.id !== client.user.id) {
      message.delete({
        timeout: 1000,
      });
      channel.send(`${member} messed up!`).catch(console.error);
      message.delete({
        timeout: 1000,
      });

      //      count = 0

      if (timeout) clearTimeout(timeout);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I hope this answer helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61396267/discord-js-delete-function?rq=1

Comment: @TerenceCheng undefined is totally different than an type error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you try to destructure the first parameter of the callback, which is a [`Message`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message) object, and a `Message` doesn't have a `message` property. If you need the `message`, you can destructure it inside the function.

So instead of

```js
client.on('message', ({ channel, content, member, message }) => {
  // ...
```

it should be

```js
client.on('message', (message) => {
  let { channel, content, member } = message
  // ...
```

This way you can use any other property and method of the `message`.

Answer (score 0):

> of undefined

look left of this... so message is undefined, log what that is at the top of `client.on`, will find that message is undefined and thus delete does not exist.